# Proving mean of two odd squares is sum of two squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From Fermat's two squares theorem we know that an odd prime p ≡ 1 (mod 4) is the sum of two squares. How do we prove a more general case: The average of two odd squares which is also congruent to 1 mod 4 is the sum of two squares.
Actually, this arises from the problem of requiring to prove m is the sum of two triangular numbers iff 4m + 1 is the sum of two squares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{2}=\left(\dfrac{p+q}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{p-q}{2}\right)^2$$